# unix - SFTP server, limited user access

Tags: unix, ssh, sftp, restrictions

The usuall question that still is challanging to implement: having one directory shared through sftp (read-only). Following this wiki: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/SFTP

The changes I made on ssh_config are:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes

Match Group sftp-users
    ChrootDirectory /home
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Then creating a user in the group:

```
useradd -M -G sftp-users username-sftp
passwd username-sftp
```

Restarting ssh to take settings:

```
restart ssh
```

Then connecting to this host from another PC provides the ftp prompt:

```
sftp username-sftp@hostname
```

But when executing the ls command, I see all directories in the root of the sftp server.

```
sftp> ls
bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  initrd.img  initrd.img.old  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  vmlinuz
```

How can I limit the access of sftp-users to only one directory?

Comment: Take a look at "restrcited shell" or "rsh" as the user accounts login shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually editing the wrong config file. The one that contains the settings is "sshd_config" and not "ssh_config".